# Is the MongoDB renameCollection command with dropTarget atomic

Tags: mongodb

I have a MongoDB collection that contains lots of documents. I need to replace all the documents with a new set of documents, i.e. basically overriding and replacing the entire collection. I'm currently doing the following:

1. Create a new temporary collection
2. Insert the new documents into this temporary collection
3. Call `renameCollection` with `dropTarget: true` from the temporary collection to the target collection

This works but my concern is whether `renameCollection` with `dropTarget: true` is atomic. In other words, I wonder if it's possible for other clients to observe the database after the target is dropped but before the rename is completed, in which case they will not find the collection and result in unavailability. Or worse, if the drop succeeded but the rename somehow failed, then the collection would be unavailable forever which is a significant concern.

I looked through the [docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/command/renameCollection/) for `renameCollection` and it says a bunch about acquiring exclusive locks on the target and source collections. I guess that implies the operation should never be observed half-done by others but I can't be 100% sure. Would appreciate if someone could give a definitive answer to my concern above. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: yes it is atomic.

There are two angles I will use to analyze this question.

First, from [source inspection](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/de94a8532566b027be899e7db1e8456128b510f7/src/mongo/db/catalog/rename_collection.cpp#L272-L327), it is clear that [the drop](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/de94a8532566b027be899e7db1e8456128b510f7/src/mongo/db/catalog/rename_collection.cpp#L317) occurs in what's called the same storage transaction as [the rename](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/de94a8532566b027be899e7db1e8456128b510f7/src/mongo/db/catalog/rename_collection.cpp#L321). The fact that the storage transaction successfully commits requires that the drop and rename have both succeeded. If one fails, the entire transaction will be rolled back. More on storage transactions in MongoDB [here](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo/blob/de94a8532566b027be899e7db1e8456128b510f7/src/mongo/db/catalog/README.md#storage-transactions).

Second, from an empirical test on a single-node replicaSet, I can observe the oplog:

```
> for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) { db.foo.insert({x: i}); }
> for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) { db.bar.insert({y: i}); }
> db.adminCommand({renameCollection: "test.foo", to: "test.bar", dropTarget: true})

> db.getSiblingDB("local").oplog.rs.find().sort({$natural: -1})
{ "op" : "c", "ns" : "test.$cmd", "ui" : UUID(...), "o" : { "renameCollection" : "test.foo", "to" : "test.bar", "stayTemp" : false, "dropTarget" : UUID(...) }, "o2" : { "numRecords" : 2 }, "ts" : Timestamp(...), "t" : NumberLong(1), "v" : NumberLong(2), "wall" : ISODate(...) }
{ "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.bar", "ui" : UUID(...), "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId(...), "y" : 2 }, "o2" : { "_id" : ObjectId(...) }, "ts" : Timestamp(...), "t" : NumberLong(1), "v" : NumberLong(2), "wall" : ISODate(...) }
{ "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.bar", "ui" : UUID(...), "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId(...), "y" : 1 }, "o2" : { "_id" : ObjectId(...) }, "ts" : Timestamp(...), "t" : NumberLong(1), "v" : NumberLong(2), "wall" : ISODate(...) }
{ "op" : "c", "ns" : "test.$cmd", "ui" : UUID(...), "o" : { "create" : "bar", "idIndex" : { "v" : 2, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_" } }, "ts" : Timestamp(...), "t" : NumberLong(1), "v" : NumberLong(2), "wall" : ISODate(...) }
{ "op" : "i", "ns" : "test.foo", "ui" : UUID(...), "o" : { "_id" : ObjectId(...), "x" : 9 }, "o2" : { "_id" : ObjectId(...) }, "ts" : Timestamp(...), "t" : NumberLong(1), "v" : NumberLong(2), "wall" : ISODate(...) }
...
```

The last query retrieves all the operations in reverse chronological order. Starting from the bottom, the last of the 10 `x` values is inserted into `test.foo`.

Then an entry represents the implicit collection creation and therefore `_id` index creation required when inserting a document into a new collection, `test.bar` in this case.

The two inserts into `test.bar` are recorded.

From there, the only side effect of renaming with `dropTarget: true` is a single oplog entry. Therefore, we can conclude that this is an atomic operation and there is no intermediate state that would be observed by another operaton.